# NLog: archive log not deleting the folder. Only file got removed after expiry

Tags: c#, nlog, archive

In our project, we have configured NLog for logging. For each day we create separate folder to log. We have configured automatic archiving, too. It all works perfectly,on the expiry time the log files got backed up, and files got removed. But the folders stay.

```
var target = new FileTarget
{
    Name = LogFileName,
    FileName = Path.Combine(logDirectoryPath, @"${date:format=yyyyMMdd}", LogFileName + ".log"),
    Layout = @"${date}|${level:uppercase=true}|${message} ${exception:format=ToString}",
    ArchiveFileName = Path.Combine(logArchievePath, LogFileName + @"_${date:format=HHmmssfff}.zip"),

    ArchiveAboveSize = 10* 1024 * 1024,
    EnableArchiveFileCompression = true,
    ArchiveEvery = FileArchivePeriod.Day,
    ArchiveNumbering = ArchiveNumberingMode.DateAndSequence,
    MaxArchiveDays = ConfiguredAdminSetting.MaxLogRetentionDay,
    EnableFileDelete = true,
};

LogManager.Configuration.Variables["baseDataPath"] = path;
LogManager.Configuration.AddTarget(LogFileName, target);
```

How can we enable folder delete for the archiving functionality?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/73783383/193178 ?

Comment: You are mixing dynamic (`fileName="${date:format=yyyyMMdd}.log"`) and static (`archiveFileName="..."`) file-archive-logic, which is not supported. See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/File-target#dynamic-vs-static-archive-logic  NLog also does not support cleaning up subfolders, so instead consider a scheduled-task / cron-job for removing old folders.